# Is it possible to count date stamped variables accross multiple sheets in Excel 2010 and list it by date?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I am very new to excel as it pertains to consolidating data and have limited experience with VBA. I have never used pivot tables. I understand that I may need to adjust my table in order to accommodate a solution but prefer not to and am not sure where to start.

In the sample below:

- There are six possible non-numeric, standardized values for each cell
  in Column F (for the sake of discussion, I have used different types
  of fruit to represent these various values).
- For each phone contact, a date stamp is generated in column E, and a
  standardized entry is made in column F.
- At any given time, there are approx 20 worksheets in the workbook. Worksheets are both added and
  omitted on a monthly basis.
- The headers of every worksheet are identical.
- There are up to 500 lines in each worksheet.  Thus, the date ranges
  in each sheet vary.
- The dates in Column E appear in order beginning with the earliest
  date in Cell E2 on Sheet 1 and the Latest Date in Cell E500 on sheet
  20.

**I need a solution that will capture the number of apples, bananas, oranges, grapes, lemons, and pears "noted" on each day.  Ideally each sheet should have its own respective summary either at the top or bottom of column F as well as a master summary of all sheets at the end of the workbook (or in another workbook). I'm looking for a "dashboard" of sorts. Can this be done? How?**

[image]

Comment: Pnuts, thanks for the question. The workflow at our company requires the sheets to remain separate.  Creating a master sheet causes other problems down the line. Based on my homework, I sense that this may keep my solution just out of reach. I'm interested in your feedback on this point. In addition,  as a more seasoned participant in this forum, can you help me understand why my question has not been well received? Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Thanks Pnuts. Live and learn. I have reviewed the link you mentioned and will make sure not to mention VBA as a possibility in my question without attempting a code.  Making attempts is not a problem. I simply had absolutely no clue where to start on this question despite careful searches online. At this point, after posting versions of this question on multiple forums, it is clear that there is no easy solution.  We will redo and try a different approach. Thanks for your feedback on Mastersheet+PT.  I'll cross my fingers that I'm not kicked off for poorly written questions.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: The code below should now arrange the totals by date.

```
Private Sub Total()

Dim apple As Integer
Dim banana As Integer
Dim grape As Integer
Dim pear As Integer
Dim lemon As Integer
Dim orange As Integer
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim comp1 As String
Dim comp2 As String

apple = 0
banana = 0
grape = 0
pear = 0
lemon = 0
orange = 0


For Each sheet In Worksheets
sheet.Activate
lastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
j = 2
'Create the header for the Totals cells
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = "Date"
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = "Apples"
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Value = "Bananas"
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 4).Value = "Grapes"
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 5).Value = "Pears"
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 6).Value = "Lemons"
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 7).Value = "Oranges"

For i = 2 To lastRow
    'Compare the date in row i to row i + 1 to see if we should add the totals or start a new daily total
    comp1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value
    comp2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value

        'Determine which variable to increment
       If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = "apple" Then
            apple = apple + 1
        ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = "banana" Then
            banana = banana + 1
        ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = "grape" Then
            grape = grape + 1
        ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = "pear" Then
            pear = pear + 1
        ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = "lemon" Then
           lemon = lemon + 1
        ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = "orange" Then
            orange = orange + 1
        Else
        End If
    If comp1 <> comp2 Then
        'If this is the last entry for this date, past the date and totals
        ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + j, 1).Value = comp1
        ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + j, 2).Value = apple
        ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + j, 3).Value = banana
        ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + j, 4).Value = grape
        ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + j, 5).Value = pear
        ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + j, 6).Value = lemon
        ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + j, 7).Value = orange
        'Clear variables for next day
        apple = 0
        banana = 0
        grape = 0
        pear = 0
        lemon = 0
        orange = 0
        'Move to next line for totals row
        j = j + 1

    Else
    End If
Next i

Next sheet

End Sub
```

This should properly total each page in the manner you are looking for, but it will not create a Grand Total for all pages.  You could implement a large array in this code to store all the values between pages, or possibly create a new function using VLookup and some For loops, but it would be rather complex.  If possible, I would try to make a formula on your Grand Total sheet to pull the data in.

Comment: Thunderblast, thanks so much for your work here. I'm not sure why my question has been poorly received by the forum. Am I correct that your answer does not address column E? Herein lies my problem. Please correct me... I need a solution that counts the items BY DATE.  So in the example above the code/formula would return the following on a table or summary sheet:  1/2: 2 apples, 2 bananas, 2 oranges, 1 grape, 1 lemon, 1/3: 1 apple, 2 grapes, 1 lemon, 1 pear......and so on. In other words, I have my dates appearing down the left hand side of the table and my variables listed across the top.

Comment: I see you specified per day and I somehow missed that... I'll take a look later today and edit once I have a working update. Should be able to add a variable and have a for loop compare the dates and if they're different, paste the day's results. I'll try to get you exact code when I have a chance though.

Comment: I edited the code and it now breaks up the data by date.  This only works per page and does not create a grand total of all sheets.  I cannot think of any sufficiently simple method of doing that.  Best of luck, and I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks again Thunderblaster.  I see that I'm asking for the impossible here.  I was a little afraid of this but wanted the help of other who know far more than me to confirm.  The contributions on this post greatly help me as I have a steep learning curve ahead.  Thanks.